# Using If statement to determine if an input is uppercase or lowercase

Tags: if-statement, uppercase, lowercase

I'm still very new to programming so bear with me. This is what I have started with:

```
letter = input ("Please enter a letter of the alphabet to be displayed as a banner: ")
while letter == **UPPERCASE**:
    ......
```

What I want to do is: if the input is an uppercase letter, to continue with the while loop, but if the input letter is lowercase to not even start the while loop. So what could I put in place of "**UPPERCASE**" to check for uppercase or lowercase and use it in a while or if statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very broad, please describe the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Well, I guess the problem is that I do not know how to differentiate between whether the input is in a uppercase letter or lowercase letter.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for whatever language you are doing your homework in?

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {"Upper case": 0, "Lower case": 0}
sen = input(">")
for i in sen:
    if i.isupper():
        d["Upper case"]+=1
    elif i.islower():
        d["Lower case"]+=1
    else:
        pass

print("Upper", d["Upper case"])
print("Lower", d["Lower case"])
```

In Python,
isupper() is a built-in method used for string handling.
islower() is a built-in method used for string handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the input as a char, you can test it with a for loop like this:

```
for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
    if (letter == i) {
        while(true) {
            //Do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

This compares the variable letter to every capital letter in the alphabet, and if it finds a match it means that yes, it is a capital letter.